# Uploading images to Google storage API in PHP without the Google cloud client PHP library?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am creating an online code editor with PHP in the back-end, where users create code projects that can include images. I created a service account on google and obtained a private key. I want using PHP to upload photos to the Google cloud storage API, using cURL, to store the images on the cloud and retrieve them;
but..

- I heard about google API PHP client library but it uses composer, and my web host doesn't allow composer or shell access, and also the library is too large and my web host has a very limited storage capacity (and that's why I considered google cloud storage in the first place for storing uploaded photos).
- I know about access tokens and was able to successfully upload image to the storage with PHP using the access token, but these tokens are temporary and only last for an hour, even the refresh tokens are also temporary.
  So..
  I want a permanent way to call the API with "native PHP" and upload to google cloud. I created a service account and obtained a private key, but wasn't able to upload to the API successfully. Here is my code so far:

  ```
       // I  previously initialized the variables $bucketName , $projectId , and $jsonKey

       function is_valid_image($file) {
        $allowed_types = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'];

        if (!in_array($file['type'], $allowed_types)) {
         return false;
        }

       return true;
       }


       if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
       if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {  
       if (is_valid_image($_FILES['image'])) {

           $localFilePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
           $objectName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
           $fileContent = base64_encode(file_get_contents($localFilePath));
           $uploadUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{$bucketName}/o?uploadType=media&name={$objectName}";
           $serviceAccountKey = json_decode($jsonKey);
           $authHeader = "Authorization: Bearer " . $serviceAccountKey['private_key'];

           $ch = curl_init($uploadUrl);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['name' => $objectName, 'content' => $fileContent]));
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
               'Content-Type: application/json',
               $authHeader,
           ]);

           $response = curl_exec($ch);
           echo $response;
           curl_close($ch);

           require "db_update.php";

       } else {
           echo 'Invalid file type. Please upload a valid image (JPEG, JPG, PNG, GIF).';
       }
   } else {
       echo 'Error uploading picture. Please try again.';
   }
  ```

But its not working and I am getting this response:

> { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials", "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid Credentials", "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ] } }

What am I doing wrong? when I used the temporary token it worked perfectly, how to do it right without using the Google storage API library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Cloud Storage API expects an access token for authentication, not the private key directly (also once you sent out your private key, it no longer is private really and I'd rotate it).

Additionally for `uploadType=media`, your payload should be the binary data of the file, not a base64-encoded string within a JSON payload.

Comment: Thank you! So the answer is to retreive the access token using the key and then authenicate using the access token